# App to show battery current or rate of change of voltage, short term info

Tags: battery, battery-life

Id like to have quick feedback about how what I do on my phone affects power usage, but cant seem to find a good widget or app for that out of the hundreds out there! Anyone know any?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure many devices will have support for something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have [Spare Parts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidapps.spare_parts) installed there is detailed information in there about the state of the battery. Also, you can find out what is the application that is sucking up most of the battery via Settings > About Phone > Battery Use.